# Does $\sum |\sin n| / n$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How can I prove if the following series converges? $$\sum_{n\geqslant1} \frac{|\sin n|}{n}$$

I can't use differential or integral calculus. I've tried using Dirichlet and Cauchy tests, but they didn't get me anywhere.

Comment: Hint: $|\sin n| \ge \frac12 (1-\cos(2n))$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assertion: For every $k$, either $|\sin(3k)|\geqslant\frac12$ or  $|\sin(3k+1)|\geqslant\frac12$ or  $|\sin(3k+2)|\geqslant\frac12$. Hence the series diverges.

*Hint:*

The assertion above uses the identity $\sin\left(\frac\pi6\right)=\frac12$ and the inequality $\mathsf{length}\left([-\frac\pi6,\frac\pi6]\right)\lt2$.

$\qquad\qquad\qquad$[image]

Comment: Do you mean $k > 0$?

Comment: @ChantryCargill Not necessarily (but one uses this for $k\gt0$, yes).

Comment: Oh never mind, I just understood what you meant.

Comment: @ChantryCargill Perfect.

Comment: My bad .$\ \ \ $